# Форма с radio buttons. Не могу получить доступ к класу в таблице

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, html-form

```css
.morning,
.fit,
.judo{
    opacity: 0;

}
#morning:checked  ~  table .morning{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <label for="morning">Morning exercise</label><input type="checkbox" id="morning">
    <label for="fit">Fitnes</label><input type="radio" id="fit">
    <label for="evening">Gymnastic</label><input type="radio" id="evening">
    <label for="judo">Judo</label><input type="radio" id="judo">
</form>

<table class="schedule">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Час</th>
        <th>Monday</th>
        <th>Thursday</th>
        <th>Wednesday</th>
        <th>Thursday</th>
        <th>Friday</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="firstPart">
        <td>06:00</td>
        <td class="morning">Morning exercise
            <span class="name">Andrey</span>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="cardio">Cardio<br>
            <span class="name"></span></td>
        <td class="morning">Morning exercise
            <span class="name">Andrey</span>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="morning weekend">Morning exercise
            <span class="name">Andrey</span>
        </td>
        <td class="weekend"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>08:00</td>
        <td class="saunaOpen">Sauna/td>
        <td class="saunaOpen">Sauna</td>
        <td class="saunaOpen">Sauna</td>
        <td class="saunaOpen">Sauna</td>
        <td class="saunaOpen">Sauna</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="firstPart">
        <td>09:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="fit week">Fitnes<br>
            <span class="name">Oleg</span>
        </td>
        <td>
        <td class="fit">Fitnes<br>
            <span class="name">Oleg</span>
        </td>
        <td class="cardio">Cardio<br>
            <span class="name">Oleg</span></td>
        <td class="cardio weekend">
            Cardio<br>
            <span class="name">Oleg</span>
        </td>
        <td class="weekend"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="firstPart">
        <td>10:00</td>
        <td class="judo">Judo">Andrey</span>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="judo">Judo<br>
            <span class="name">Andrey</span>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="judo">Judo<br>
            <span class="name">Andrey</span>
        </td>
        <td class="morning weekend">Morning exercise
            <span class="name">Andrey</span>
        </td>
        <td class="weekend"></td>
    </tr>
```

Форма с `radio buttons`. Не могу получить доступ к класу в таблице.Чтобы сменить видимость.
Как можно получить доступ к:

```
#morning:checked  ~  table .morning{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: А кстати, радио-кнопкам точно не забыли добавить name? Они включаются и всё) *Насколько радио-кнопок с одинаковыми `name="что-то"` переключаются между собой при клике.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Они обернуты в дополнительный тег `<form>` — с этого момента можно сказать досвидание CSS, т.к. его селекторы не позволяют "выйти" из текущего блока и связаться с элементами из соседнего блока. Они должны быть либо одинакового уровня, либо второй должен быть ниже первого.

Убрать form, нормально сработает:

(у вас было несколько опечаток в коде, можно перекопировать именно отсюда)

```css
.morning,
.fit,
.judo{
    opacity: 0;

}
#morning:checked  ~  table .morning{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<label for="morning">Morning exercise</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="morning">
<label for="fit">Fitnes</label>
<input type="radio" id="fit">
<label for="evening">Gymnastic</label>
<input type="radio" id="evening">
<label for="judo">Judo</label><input type="radio" id="judo">


<table class="schedule">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Час</th>
      <th>Monday</th>
      <th>Thursday</th>
      <th>Wednesday</th>
      <th>Thursday</th>
      <th>Friday</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="firstPart">
      <td>06:00</td>
      <td class="morning">Morning exercise
        <span class="name">Andrey</span>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="cardio">Cardio<br>
        <span class="name"></span></td>
      <td class="morning">Morning exercise
        <span class="name">Andrey</span>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="morning weekend">Morning exercise
        <span class="name">Andrey</span>
      </td>
      <td class="weekend"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>08:00</td>
      <td class="saunaOpen">Sauna</td>
      <td class="saunaOpen">Sauna</td>
      <td class="saunaOpen">Sauna</td>
      <td class="saunaOpen">Sauna</td>
      <td class="saunaOpen">Sauna</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="firstPart">
      <td>09:00</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="fit week">Fitnes<br>
        <span class="name">Oleg</span>
      </td>
      <td>
      <td class="fit">Fitnes<br>
        <span class="name">Oleg</span>
      </td>
      <td class="cardio">Cardio<br>
        <span class="name">Oleg</span></td>
      <td class="cardio weekend">
        Cardio<br>
        <span class="name">Oleg</span>
      </td>
      <td class="weekend"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="firstPart">
      <td>10:00</td>
      <td class="judo">Judo <br>
        <span class="name">Andrey</span>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="judo">Judo<br>
        <span class="name">Andrey</span>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="judo">Judo<br>
        <span class="name">Andrey</span>
      </td>
      <td class="morning weekend">Morning exercise
        <span class="name">Andrey</span>
      </td>
      <td class="weekend"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Если этот form сильно нужен, уже идет в ход JavaScript:

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/zxrh83bq/)

```js
(function(){

let classmorn = document.querySelectorAll('table .morning');
let idmorn = document.getElementById('morning');
/* запускаем функцию каждый раз, когда чекбокс меняется */
idmorn.addEventListener('change', function(){
  for(let i = 0; i < classmorn.length; i++){
    /* которая перебрав все классы - добавляет или убирает у них класс show */
    classmorn[i].classList.toggle('show');
  }
});

})();
```

```css
.morning, .fit, .judo{ opacity: 0; }

.show {opacity: 1 !important;}
/* important не рекомендуется часто использовать, но тут можно 
   Он дает высший приоритет, и гарантированно перебивает стили всех остальных селекторов */
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="morning">Morning exercise</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="morning">
  <label for="fit">Fitnes</label>
  <input type="radio" id="fit">
  <label for="evening">Gymnastic</label>
  <input type="radio" id="evening">
  <label for="judo">Judo</label><input type="radio" id="judo">
</form>


<table class="schedule">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Час</th>
      <th>Monday</th>
      <th>Thursday</th>
      <th>Wednesday</th>
      <th>Thursday</th>
      <th>Friday</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="firstPart">
      <td>06:00</td>
      <td class="morning">Morning exercise
        <span class="name">Andrey</span>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="cardio">Cardio<br>
        <span class="name"></span></td>
      <td class="morning">Morning exercise
        <span class="name">Andrey</span>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="morning weekend">Morning exercise
        <span class="name">Andrey</span>
      </td>
      <td class="weekend"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>08:00</td>
      <td class="saunaOpen">Sauna</td>
      <td class="saunaOpen">Sauna</td>
      <td class="saunaOpen">Sauna</td>
      <td class="saunaOpen">Sauna</td>
      <td class="saunaOpen">Sauna</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="firstPart">
      <td>09:00</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="fit week">Fitnes<br>
        <span class="name">Oleg</span>
      </td>
      <td>
      <td class="fit">Fitnes<br>
        <span class="name">Oleg</span>
      </td>
      <td class="cardio">Cardio<br>
        <span class="name">Oleg</span></td>
      <td class="cardio weekend">
        Cardio<br>
        <span class="name">Oleg</span>
      </td>
      <td class="weekend"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="firstPart">
      <td>10:00</td>
      <td class="judo">Judo <br>
        <span class="name">Andrey</span>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="judo">Judo<br>
        <span class="name">Andrey</span>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="judo">Judo<br>
        <span class="name">Andrey</span>
      </td>
      <td class="morning weekend">Morning exercise
        <span class="name">Andrey</span>
      </td>
      <td class="weekend"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

http://learn.javascript.ru/ - - основы JS, удобно разложены по пунктам.

Comment: Я код вставил небрежно просто вырезал, тк главное было узнать можно ли получить доступ. Но я понял что только через js, большое спасибо вам.